# How to launch IIS Express without elevation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My VS 2015 was running fine, until I exited IIS Express manually.

I was making a one-line change to the applicationhost.config file. **I stopped IIS Express**. Pressed F5 in VS, and I got an "Access is denied error":

[image]

I restored the change I made in applicationhost.config, but the problem will not go away. I can now overcome this only by starting Visual Studio in administrator mode.

How can I restore to the previous situation?

Comment: Use Jexus Manager http://jexusmanager.com to check if there is a reserved URL at that port under HTTP API page.

Comment: Thanks, but what is a reserved URL?

Comment: https://jexus.lextudio.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html